# SELECT not woking inside IF condition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Below ORACLE query works fine.

```
DECLARE ABC VARCHAR2(50) :='SOME VALUE';
BEGIN
IF (ABC = 'SOME VALUE')
THEN 
dbms_output.put_line('1');
ELSE
dbms_output.put_line('2');
END IF;
END;
```

But if I use SELECT inside IF then it throws an error.

```
DECLARE ABC VARCHAR2(50) :='SOME VALUE';
BEGIN
IF (ABC = 'SOME VALUE')
THEN 
select cast('1' as VARCHAR(50)) from dual;
ELSE
select cast('2' as VARCHAR(50)) from dual;
END IF;
END;
```

ERROR:

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Comment: wou want to select where?.. to output? then use dbms_output, if to table then select into tablename, same if you want to variable...

Comment: in plsql you have to select into variable. 
select  cast('1' as VARCHAR(50)) into v_abc from dual;

Answer (score 1):

Select variable using into clause

```
DECLARE ABC VARCHAR2(50) :='SOME VALUE';
BEGIN
IF (ABC = 'SOME VALUE')
THEN 
select cast('1' as VARCHAR(50)) into ABC from dual;
ELSE
select cast('2' as VARCHAR(50)) into ABC from dual;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: that `cast('1' as VARCHAR(50))` is unnecessary here.

Comment: My point is that you need to select columns into variables using into clause.One can cast to varchar(50) if he wants because here he may want only 50 characters

Comment: select cast('1' as VARCHAR(50)) into ABC from dual; this query is just a sample query I want to display based on IF condition.

Comment: @PratapMane is above answer makes sense or you want something else?

Comment: Still no success. ABC already has value and I do not want to reassign it. I just need to execute a query based on IF condition. It seems ORACLE does not support SELECT query within IF as like we do in T-SQL.

Comment: @PratapMane `SELECT` is pure `SQL`, `SELECT..INTO` is `PL/SQL`. Both are completely different.

Answer (score 1):

- You are mixing `SQL` with `PL/SQL`. They are different, you cannot have a **SELECT** statement inside PL/SQL block without an **INTO** clause.
- There is no need to use **CAST** since you have already declared the variable as `VARCHAR250)`.
- There is no point in just issuing a `SELECT .. INTO` without doing anything with the value you are fetching.

For example,

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    ABC VARCHAR2(50) :='SOME VALUE';
  3  BEGIN
  4    IF (ABC = 'SOME VALUE') THEN
  5      SELECT '1' INTO abc FROM dual;
  6    ELSE
  7      SELECT '2' INTO abc FROM dual;
  8    END IF;
  9    dbms_output.put_line('Output is '||abc);
 10  END;
 11  /
Output is 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I need to insert this value in temp table

Comment: Simply use an `INSERT` statement, use the variable `abc` in the VALUES.